# How do this Python Coderbyte function work?

Tags: python

The problem is add up all numbers from 1 to num. e.g: If the input is 4 then your program should return 10 because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

so this is my solution

```
def SimpleAdding(num):
  total = []
  for i in range(1,num+1):
    total.append(i)

 return sum(total)
```

and this is the top solution of the problem

```
def SimpleAdding(num): 
    if num == 1:
      return 1
    else:
      return num + SimpleAdding(num-1)
```

I wanna know how this kind of solution work without looping. It doesn't make sense to me at all. I'm just a beginner btw.

Comment: this is a recursive solution, which is generally avoided in idiomatic python

Comment: use (N*(N+1))/2

Comment: Top solution uses a thing called function recursion, basically you can just initialize a function that will call itself over and over again

Comment: Also please consider using snake_case for naming variables and functions instead of CamelCase

Comment: oh..I don't know that there's something like that

Comment: @Madi7 Okay, I will try to change their default function name next time

Answer (score 1):

here is diagram

[image]

def SimpleAdding(num): 
    if num == 1:
      return 1
    else:
      return num + SimpleAdding(num-1)

this is recursion

for SimpleAdding(5) this is happening :

```
1. 5 + SimpleAdding(4)
2. 5 + 4+ SimpleAdding(3) # recall again as no exit condition meet
3. 5+ 4+ 3 + SimpleAdding(2)
4. 5 + 4+ 3+ 2+ SimpleAdding(1)
5. 5+ 4 + 3+ 2+ 1 # finally giving 1
```

Comment: wow, I gotta learn this recursion thing. thank you!